# Select last sibling in each group of siblings

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I want to select the last sibling in a group of elements, but there are more than one group in the parent container.

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="select"></div><!-- padding-top -->
  <div class="select"></div>
  <div class="select"></div><!-- padding-bottom -->

  <p>Some text</p>

  <div class="select"></div><!-- padding-top -->
  <div class="select"></div>
  <div class="select"></div>
  <div class="select"></div>
  <div class="select"></div><!-- padding-bottom -->

<div>
```

So in this case, for every clump of `.select` elements, I need to add `padding-top` to the first one and `padding-bottom` to the last one. The tricky part is that the clump of `.select` elements can be infinitely large/small, but the first and last elements need padding.

This example works for the top padding...

```
// add padding-top to all elements
.select {
  padding-top: 1em;
}

// remove it for general direct siblings
.select + .select {
  padding-top: 0;
}

// this will only add to the last .select in the parent container, 
// not the last in each clump of .select elements
.select + .select:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

But the bottom padding for the last element in the clump is what I'm having issues with.

I can't add wrapper elements because this is pseudo generated code. JS would also make this a fairly straightforward solution, but I'd rather exhaust all of my CSS only solutions first.

Edit: The HTML structure is 100% arbitrary as it will be generated by the user in a WYSIWYG. However, there will be some sections of `.select` elements next to each other.

Comment: are you sure there will always be 2 groups?  with 3 elements on top and 5 on bottom?

Comment: You could add the padding/margin to any ``<p>`` after a ``.select`` and to the wrapper element.

Comment: is there any reason why you can't fake it by adding padding-top to the `<p>` after a `.select`?  And then you can add extra padding-bottom to `.select:last-child` to catch that last one.

Answer (score 3):

```
.wrapper>*:not(.select) + .select, .wrapper>.select + *:not(.select) {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
.wrapper>.select:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

If positioning was not the issue, and setting a `margin-top` on the next element doesn't do it (for example you have a background on `.select` and you actually need bottom padding on the last item in the group), well... you can't select the previous sibling with CSS.

So here's a solution using jQuery:

```js
$('.wrapper>*:not(.select)').each(function() {
  $(this).prev(".select").css({
    'padding-bottom': '20px'
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}
.select {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
/* ignore CSS above, it's for coloring and padding so you see elements */

.select {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.select ~ .select {
  padding-top: 0;
}
*:not(.select) + .select {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.wrapper>.select:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="select">select</div>
  <!-- padding-top -->
  <div class="select">select</div>
  <div class="select">select</div>
  <!-- padding-bottom -->

  <p>Some text</p>

  <div class="select">select</div>
  <!-- padding-top -->
  <div class="select">select</div>
  <div class="select">select</div>
  <div class="select">select</div>
  <div class="select">select</div>
  <!-- padding-bottom -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question, I know, but I just had the same problem so thought this might be helpful for someone. Using :not() worked for me; I used borders instead of paddings for the example so it's more visible.

```css
.wrapper * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.select {
    border-top: 30px solid #f00;
}
.select:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 30px solid #f00;
}
.select + .select {
    border-top: 0;
}
.select + :not(.select) {
    border-top: 30px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    
    <div class="select">Select 1</div><!-- padding-top -->
    <div class="select">Select 2</div>
    <div class="select">Select 3</div><!-- padding-bottom -->

    <p>Some text</p>

    <div class="select">Select 4</div><!-- padding-top -->
    <div class="select">Select 5</div>
    <div class="select">Select 6</div>
    <div class="select">Select 7</div>
    <div class="select">Select 8</div><!-- padding-bottom -->
    
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the structure always 2 groups of `div` separated by a `p`?

And is the `padding` meant to create space at top/bottom of each group?
And if so, would `margin` be okay instead?

Then here is a sample doing like so.

```css
.wrapper div:first-child,
.wrapper p {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.wrapper div:last-child,
.wrapper p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* just for coloring making it visible */
.wrapper {
  background-color: #666;
  border: 1px solid  black;
}
.wrapper p,
.select {
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="select">1</div><!-- padding-top -->
  <div class="select">2</div>
  <div class="select">3</div><!-- padding-bottom -->

  <p>Some text</p>

  <div class="select">1</div><!-- padding-top -->
  <div class="select">2</div>
  <div class="select">3</div>
  <div class="select">4</div>
  <div class="select">5</div><!-- padding-bottom -->

<div>
```

If it needs to be `padding` and you don't want to use script, this might work.

```css
.wrapper div:first-child {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.wrapper div:last-of-type {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* just for coloring making it visible */
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid  black;
  background-color: #666;
}
.wrapper p,
.select {
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="select">1</div>
  <div class="select">2</div>
  <div class="select">3</div>
  <p>Some text</p>  
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="select">1</div>
  <div class="select">2</div>
  <div class="select">3</div>
  <div class="select">4</div>
  <div class="select">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ha, it doesn't work differently! I didn't notice the change in markup :). So... it's a no-no on the initial markup. Can't be done via CSS only if it actually needs bottom-padding on last of group. I hope they'll implement the target specifier in compound selectors in CSS4.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Your're right, I made a markup change instead of script, and I hope so too, a parent and previous selector is welcome ... and good you saw I'm no magician :)

Comment: @LGSon no, that format will not always be the same. The `<p>` could be a different element or it could be missing, or replaced by 10 other elements. The structure is completely arbitrary.

Comment: @DaronSpence So according to your edit, there will always be `.select` groups and it is those which needs a top/bottom margin?

Comment: @LGSon correct. Well, they need padding, but that's beside the point!

Comment: @DaronSpence If you must have padding you need script until CSS parent and/or previous sibling selector is available, or if you can add an extra class to the first/last `.select` in each group. With margin you can get away with CSS only as long as the format is `.wrapper` + `.select` + `something else` + `.select` + `.wrapper`. If `something else` is missing the margin will only be on first/last `.select` ... and then you should accept Andrei's answer as s/he cover those better than I.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to touch the .select elements, just add padding top and bottom to the .wrapper, and margins top and bottom to the p

Comment: This is as well a good way if `padding` isn't a must. Adding a code sample to your answer might give you up votes instead of down votes. +1