# last-of-type applied to elements that do not exist

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Can't find this exact question so here goes...

What i originally wanted to achieve was essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363563/select-last-sibling-in-each-group-of-siblings), but for Rows instead of Divs. after some futher research, i'm not sure what i want to achive is possible in the exact way i assume it should be, but this has lead me to the discovery of the last-of-type oddness.

Can anyone please explain how last-of-type is working in this scenario? I have last-of-type being applied to non existing elements, and not applied to existing ones (hope that made sense).

**The CSS Rule:**

```
.row-detail:last-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
```

An example:

```js
SampleTable = $('#sampleTable').DataTable();

$('.detailButton').on('click', function() {
 
  var button = $(this);
  var icon = button.find('i.fa');
  icon.toggleClass('fa-eye');
  icon.toggleClass('fa-eye-slash');
  button.blur();
  
  var row = button.closest('tr');
  var dataTableRow = SampleTable.row(row);
  console.log(dataTableRow.child.isShown())
  if (!dataTableRow.child.isShown()) {
    
    dataTableRow.child(buildDetailRows()).show();
  }
  else {
  
    dataTableRow.child.hide();
  }
});

function buildDetailRows() {
  
  return $('<tr class="row-detail"><td>Detail 1</td><td>Detail r1 c1</td><td>Detail r1 c2</td><td>Detail r1 c3</td></tr><tr class="row-detail"><td>Detail 2</td><td>Detail r2 c1</td><td>Detail r2 c2</td><td>Detail r2 c3</td></tr><tr class="row-detail"><td>Detail 3</td><td>Detail r3 c1</td><td>Detail r3 c2</td><td>Detail r3 c3</td></tr>');
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.row-detail:last-of-type {  
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="table">
  <table id="sampleTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Detail</th>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="detailButton btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="button">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>row1 Col1</td>
        <td>row1 Col2</td>
        <td>row1 Col3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
          <button class="detailButton btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="button">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>row2 Col1</td>
        <td>row2 Col2</td>
        <td>row2 Col3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
          <button class="detailButton btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="button">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>row3 Col1</td>
        <td>row3 Col2</td>
        <td>row3 Col3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

***PLEASE NOTE: this is sort of delayed / laggy / slightly different to non jsFiddle implimentation of the same code. The fiddle, for some reason only applies the last row's style when the previous detail rows are closed - it works better not in jsFiddle.***

The point is that when you click a detail button, it creates the DataTable's child row. these are just table rows, nothing special, but the last-of-type is only being applied to the very last child row in the verry last table row.

**What i expected to see was:**

- Click row1 detail button: 3rd child row gets styled
- Click another
  detail button (below the first), the previously styled child row is
  unstyled and the new row (being the acctual "last-of-type" has this
  rule applied).

**What actuality happens**
No child rows are styled with the "last-of-type" style except the 3rd child row in the last row of the table - despite not existing until clicked. ***In the case of jsFiddle, you need to close previous detail rows to "enable" the style on the last one - as stated above, this "close previous detail" is not required in my codebase - it seems to be a fiddle nuance.***

Further oddness in jsFillde indicates it styles the last row when all three detail buttons are active, but not when just two are.

Incidentally, i get the same behaviour with last-child.
(Using Chrome).

Comment: Pseudo-classes are applied to elements, not classes of elements. When you add a class to the mix, as you have, the class acts like a filter and only applies the pseudo-class if the element has the class.

Comment: Yes, this is my understanding of Pseudo classes "only applies the pseudo class if the element has the class". The point i'm making is there is no class untill you click the button, so it should apply that rule to the newly added element (with the matching class)...It does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `:last-of-type`, the "type" refers to the tagname - it selects all the elements that are the last ones with that tagname among their siblings.  In this case, then, the elements it's going to be applied to are `tr` elements, so it'll only match when the element is the last `tr` among its siblings.

Note that selectors are matched *independently*. The fact that you further qualified it with `.row-detail` has *no effect* on how `:last-of-type` matches. Those are two totally independent filters: "do I have .row-detail class" and "am I the last tr among my siblings".

Thus, this'll match when you expand the third row, because the "detail rows" are added after all the other rows, so the last `tr` in the table is also a `.row-detail`. It *doesn't* match when you expand any of the other rows, because then the last `.row-detail` element is *not* the last `tr` among its siblings.

What you actually want *does* exist in the specs, but is only implemented by Safari currently: `:nth-last-child(1 of tr.row-detail)`.  The `of <selector>` argument to `:nth-child()` and `:nth-last-child()` restricts the counting just to among the elements matching the selector.  File bugs on browser vendors to support it!

Comment: Safari shipped this feature in version 9 alongside `:matches()`, `:not(<complex selector-list>)` and a handful of other level 4 features, so we've had one public-facing (i.e. not guarded by flag) implementation for a number of years now. Test case: `data:text/html,<style>:nth-last-child(1 of .cls) { color: red }</style><p class=cls>a<p class=cls>b<p>c`

Comment: OK thanks @Zanthir - Looks like i was getting in a pickle with the css rules and selectors - the fact that you say this is only implemented in safari, is enough to make me move on. Also looks like a lack of full understanding on my part - types (elements?) vs classes etc.